# Is there a way to configure closing indentation in multiline function call?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, indentation, lint

In visual studio code, when editing a typescript file, if I want to reindent this piece of code with the reindent command :

```js
this.someClass.method(
    argumentA,
    argumentB,
);
```

it would change it to :

```js
this.someClass.method(
    argumentA,
    argumentB,
    ); // <-- messed up indentation
```

And the rest of the file will have shifted indentation from there.

Is there a way to fix this behavior, i.e. to tell the editor to put the closing parenthesis at the same indentation level as the beginning of the call statement ?

Comment: Never used this command, but it seems to do strange things. What happens if you try `Format Document` instead? Also [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) is awesome.

Comment: Thanks ! Looks like `Format document` works as expected !
I wonder what is the difference then. If you put that as an answer, I would mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the `Format Document` command is the recommended way to prettify a file in VSCode.

Also, I *highly* recommend [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to do this on ave automatically. Once you get used to it, it's *so* nice.